# Pyspark: Prevent Column value from changing once calculated

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which I am using to store keys generated for encryption. I use a UDF to generate a key for each row but whenever the dataframe is queried the keys change. I have tried wrapping the function in lit() but it still changes. How can I make this column Immutable?

Code:

```
def generate_key():
    encryptionKey = Fernet.generate_key().decode('utf-8')
    return encryptionKey

get_key = udf(generate_key, StringType())

def key_table(df):
    df        = df.select("id").withColumn('encKey', lit(get_key()))
    return df
```

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zXcv.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A column in my pyspark dataframe changes each time it is queried, how can I prevent this column from changing?

Comment: how is your `key_df`?

Comment: Theres an image of the output. It returns a dataframe with an ID and Key, but whenever it is queried the Key changes every time. Any command keyDF.select("*"), or keyDF.show(). Will cause the encKey column to change

Answer (score 2):

UDF in Spark are rerun anytime the data is evicted out of memory and Spark has to recompute the column, if your UDF is `deterministic` (i.e) always returns the same output given the same input, then this causes no problem. However in your case the UDF is `non-deterministic`. One way to overcome this problem would be to [`checkpoint`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.checkpoint.html) the dataframe and then using it further.